# Parameter error when using VB Concatenate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm using the following VBA from a friend that works quite well for concatenating items in MS Access.

```vb
 Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSql As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null'
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSql = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

I call this function successfully from the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tblData ( SubjectNumber, RECDATE, RecordedDoses, DoseTimes, FoodType, ProgrammingComments )
SELECT d.SubjectNumber, d.RECDATE, Count(d.RECTIME) AS RecordedDoses, ConcatRelated("RECTIME", "qryDump2", "SubjectNumber= """ & d.[SubjectNumber]  & """"  & " AND RECDATE=" & FORMAT(d.RECDATE, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")) AS DoseTimes, ConcatRelated("FoodType", "qryDump2", "SubjectNumber= """ & d.[SubjectNumber]  & """"  & " AND RECDATE=" & FORMAT(d.RECDATE, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")) AS FoodType, d.Visit AS ProgrammingComments
FROM qryDump2 AS d
GROUP BY d.SubjectNumber, d.RECDATE, d.Visit
HAVING Count(d.RECTIME)<2 Or Count(d.RECTIME)>2
ORDER BY d.RECDATE;
```

The query above references several tables and queries. The issue is, when my criteria is a specific subject, e.g. "1011002", the concatenate function has no problem running. However, when the criteria is anything else, e.g. Prompt criteria, referencing a text box, etc, I get the fun "Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1. If I switch my criteria back to a string, e.g. "1011002" it works again. When using prompt criteria, if I type the same item in, i.e. 1011002, the error appears again.

What am I missing?

Edit: The query that is called a few items down the line that references the criteria I mentioned above is as follows:

```
SELECT tblDump.SubjectNumber, IIf(tblDump.SD_DAY=1,tblDump.RECDATE,tblDump.RECDATE-1) AS RECDATE, IIf(tblDump.DRUG_Q1=1,tblDump.RECTIME,tblDump.DRUG_Q6) AS RECTIME, tblDump.FoodType, IIf(IIf(tblDump.SD_DAY=1,tblDump.RECDATE,tblDump.RECDATE-1)=tblL.DiscontDate,"DayOfDiscontinuation",IIf(IIf(tblDump.SD_DAY=1,tblDump.RECDATE,tblDump.RECDATE-1)=tblL.CompletionDate,"CompletionDate",IIf(IIf(tblDump.SD_DAY=1,tblDump.RECDATE,tblDump.RECDATE-1)=tblL.[2],"Visit2"))) AS Visit
FROM tblDump LEFT JOIN tblL ON tblDump.SubjectNumber = tblL.SubjectNumber
WHERE tblDump.SubjectNumber=Forms![frm]![test];
```

The where statement, when I use an actual value, e.g. "1011002" (subject number is text and not a number even though the example I gave is a number), the concatenate function works. When I use what is above, i.e. referencing a form field, I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: What do you mean by "*criteria*"?  That word appears nowhere in your code.  Please use specific variable and parameter names when describing error conditions.

Comment: Also, that's AccessBasic/VBA and *not* VB.Net.

Comment: I updated to include the criteria I mentioned and fixed the vb/vba snafu.

Answer (score 0):

The where clause isn't checking to see if the text has spaces, maybe trim the form data before putting it into the function call and see if that stops your code from creating an empty where clause in the sql.